# BigQuery : Inconsistency in Last Modified date of Table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, google-iam

I have a customised cloud dataflow job based on java which updates a bigquery table in destination project, I stopped that job a ~month ago on 12th August 2023.

However I looked at cloud logging, I can see there are AppendRows operations called after 12th August.

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "message": "OK"
    },
    "authenticationInfo": {},
    "requestMetadata": {
      "requestAttributes": {},
      "destinationAttributes": {}
    },
    "serviceName": "bigquery.googleapis.com",
    "methodName": "google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.BigQueryWrite.AppendRows",
    "authorizationInfo": [
      {
        "resource": "projects/test-development/datasets/test_dataset/tables/test_table",
        "permission": "bigquery.tables.updateData",
        "granted": true,
        "resourceAttributes": {}
      }
    ],
    "resourceName": "projects/test-development/datasets/test_dataset/tables/test_table",
    "metadata": {
      "tableDataChange": {
        "streamName": "projects/test-development/datasets/test_dataset/tables/test_table/streams/Cic2NTA3YTM0My0wMDAwLTIzMjgtOGEyZS0wODllMDgyZmRhNzA6czY",
        "insertedRowsCount": "13",
        "reason": "WRITE_API"
      },
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.BigQueryAuditMetadata"
    }
  },
  "insertId": "ofg54hdtzg0",
  "resource": {
    "type": "bigquery_table",
    "labels": {
      "table_id": "test_table",
      "dataset_id": "test_dataset",
      "project_id": "test-development"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-08-26T20:40:17.174691Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "logName": "projects/test-development/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access",
  "operation": {
    "id": "7923749237482-projects/test-development/datasets/test_dataset/tables/test_table/streams/Cic2NTA3YTM0My0wMDAwLTIzMjgtOGEyZS0wODllMDgyZmRhNzA6czY",
    "producer": "bigquery.googleapis.com",
    "last": true
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-26T20:40:17.847787645Z"
}
```

But If I go and check the table `Details` tab on BigQuery console and it shows `Last modified` date as `12th August 2023`.

I am wondering why there is inconsistency in BigQuery Table Last Modified date or Is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Did you double check the project.dataset.table involved?

Comment: Yes I verified multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy you're observing between the Last Modified date in the BigQuery Table and the AppendRows actions logged in Cloud Logging can be clarified by understanding how BigQuery handles data streaming and metadata updates.

The "Last Modified date" displayed on the BigQuery Table Details page typically signifies when alterations were made to the table's schema or metadata. It is generally not updated to reflect streaming inserts or the addition of new rows. This date mainly pertains to changes in the table's structure or attributes. Conversely, the AppendRows operations recorded in Cloud Logging correspond to streaming inserts or data updates within the table. These operations occur when new rows are added to the table through a streaming data source like Cloud Dataflow.

In your scenario, it's anticipated that you continue to see AppendRows operations in Cloud Logging even after stopping the Dataflow job. This is because these operations capture changes in the table's data content. On the other hand, the "Last Modified" date in the Table Details tab reflects modifications to the table's metadata or schema, not its data.

In summary, the inconsistency you're witnessing arises from the distinction in the meaning of the "Last Modified" date in the BigQuery Console (related to metadata adjustments) and the AppendRows operations logged in Cloud Logging (associated with data adjustments).

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre my answer was not on multiple questions. It's just the SAME question. I opted to just delete my first answer as I answered my second via the tool I was using. I just wanted to help the OP in this use case. Also, this answer has been originally accepted by the OP.